# newtheorem{example} changing name in document

Tags: newtheorem

Preamble: \newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Beispiel}

Now I want to change {Beispiel} to {Beispiele} for only one time in my document.
How to do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to illustrate your qestion?

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) it is customary here to provide a full minimal example instead of posting just sniplets, that makes it a lot easier to help. (3) I'd just make another theorem environment, even if it is just going to be used once.

Comment: I support daleif's idea: `\newtheorem{examples}[theorem]{Beispiele}` is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Following daleif and egreg's suggestions in the comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Beispiel}
\newtheorem{examples}[theorem]{Beispiele}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Some theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{example}
Some example
\end{example}

\begin{examples}
Multiple examples
\end{examples}

\end{document}
```

[image: theorems]